# Why won't my php configure on my Mac (El Capitan)

Tags: php

I'm trying to configure php 5.6.25 and configure fails each time.  In fact, any version of php I download will not compile.  Below is the config.log link with the error details. I'll also display a image snippet here:

[image: snippet]

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6XaSVDKz)

Comment: Do you have XCode installed? Try running "xcode-select --install" on the terminal.

Comment: Try instaling XCode. Run the following in terminal to install: xcode-select --install

Comment: xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Comment: Well, try updating the software. Also, what are your exact steps?

Comment: @BVengerov I'm working with a fresh install and have updated just about everything I can think of.  Basically, I downloaded the php tar file from php.net, extracted it, then ran ./configure.  I assume there is still a library missing but I'm not sure.  I also thought about MAC System Integrity Protection but I was able to configure other apps already.